# Spring security issue with embedded google doc viewer

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Google document viewer along with JSP in my Spring MVC application to display pdf files. It was working well, pdf files were able to be seen until Spring Security was added to this application. After adding Spring Security, in a place where a pdf should be shown, now the login page source code is shown. If I disable Spring Security, then I can view the pdf.

I've tried changing the interceptor url pattern with `permitAll` in different ways including Google doc url, but none of the changes resolved the issue.

Here is the place where I am using the Google doc viewer to display a pdf

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=${fchPath}/invoice/pdfView?_invoicePath=${invoiceQueue.invoicePath}&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></iframe>
```

where =${fchPath}/invoice/pdfView?_invoicePath=${invoiceQueue.invoicePath} will be resolved to the url (http://host/AccessWeb/invoice/pdfView?_invoicePath) which invokes a Spring controller, which in turn download the pdf file to display in the browser.

All other pages are working as expected with Spring Security enabled.

Here is my spring-security xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern='/user/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/invoice/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/settings/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern='/report/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/user/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/index?statusMessage=AUTH_FAILED" 
            username-parameter="userName"
            password-parameter="password" 
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="userAuthFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="userAuthSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index?statusMessage=LOGOUT_SUCCESS" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="fchUserAuthService" ></authentication-provider>

    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

fchUserAuthService is the bean which authenticating the user.

Any help will be highly appreciated.